# Create list of folders with a matching (but not identical) ending

Tags: shell-script

I have a directory that contains folders ending in .ctpre or .ctpost (e.g. "15.ctpre"), along with other files/folders. I want to make a list that includes only subjects with both pre and post folders, and I only want to keep the matching subject ID (e.g. "15").

Here is the code I have right now:

```
#Make a list of folders that include .ct
find *.ct* -maxdepth 0 -fprint temp1
#In this list, remove the .ctpre and .ctpost extensions
sed 's/.ctpre//' temp1 > temp2
sed 's/.ctpost//' temp2 > temp3
#Sort the list
sort temp3 > temp4
#Print/save only duplicate entries on the list
uniq -d temp4 > sub_list
#Delete temp files
rm temp1 | rm temp2 | rm temp3 | rm temp4
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Can you provide a list of sample filenames, and show the output you want?

Comment: Note that `rm` doesn't do anything with stdin, so piping into it is not useful. You want `rm temp1; rm temp2; rm temp3; rm temp4` or `rm temp1 temp2 temp3 temp4` or `rm temp{1,2,3,4}` or `rm temp[1-4]`

Comment: Example folder names: 15.ctpre, 15.ctpost, 16.ctpre, 17.ctpre, 17.ctpost. Example output: 15, 17

Comment: Thanks for the note about 'rm' and the variety of options.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All your script in one line

```
for file in *.ctp{ost,re} ; do echo ${file%.*} ; done | sort | uniq -d > sub_list
```

Or (thanks to [drewbenn](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4443/drewbenn) for comment)

```
for f in *.ctpre; do [ -d ${f%.*}.ctpost ] && echo ${f%.*} ; done > sub_list
```

Comment: @drewbenn It is subtle but Costas' use of `uniq -d` has the effect of a logical AND.

Comment: @drewbenn nice idea, I'd like it. If you do not intend to make your own post I'l add it as variant

Comment: Thanks Costas and @drewbeen, all 3 of those lines worked. I didn't know about that output option for `echo`

Comment: @Costas, in your second line, what does `[ -d ${f%.*}.ctpost ]` do? Does it work the same as `test -d`?

Comment: @BrentWomble Yes, the `[` is synonim of `test`